# Getting "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'on' of undefined or null reference" on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, wordpress

Please check the below code. This is working fine on Firefox and chrome but giving following error on Internet Explorer 11. So the needed wordpress image pop-up feature is not working on IE.

**SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'on' of undefined or null reference**

```
$(document).on('click', '.dfiFeaturedImage', function() {

        current = $(this);

        if( null !== current) {

            var dfi_uploader = wp.media({

                title: WP_SPECIFIC.mediaSelector_title,
                button: {
                    text: WP_SPECIFIC.mediaSelector_buttonText
                },
                multiple: false,

            }).on('select', function() {

                var attachment = dfi_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON(),
                    fullSize = attachment.url,
                    imgUrl = (typeof attachment.sizes.thumbnail === "undefined") ? fullSize : attachment.sizes.thumbnail.url,
                    imgUrlTrimmed, fullUrlTrimmed;

                imgUrlTrimmed = imgUrl.replace(WP_SPECIFIC.upload_url, "");
                fullUrlTrimmed = fullSize.replace(WP_SPECIFIC.upload_url, "");

                var featuredBox = current.parent();

                featuredBox.find('.fImg').attr({
                    'src': imgUrl,
                    'data-src': fullSize
                });

                featuredBox.find('.dfiFeaturedImage').addClass('hasFeaturedImage');

                var dfiFeaturedImages = [imgUrlTrimmed, fullUrlTrimmed];

                /**
                 * Check if medium sized image exists
                 * @type object
                 */
                var medium = attachment.url;
                if( typeof attachment.sizes.medium !== "undefined" ) {
                    medium = attachment.sizes.medium.url;
                }

                featuredBox.find('img').attr('src', medium).fadeIn(200);
                featuredBox.find('input.dfiImageHolder').val(dfiFeaturedImages);

            }).open();  
        }

        return false;

    });
```

Comment: if you change your code so that the `.on` statement for the `dfi_uploader` is in a different call, can you `console.log(dfi_uploader)` and see if it returns a jquery reference? like `});console.log(dfi_uploader);dfi_uploader.on(....);`

Comment: again showing same error at dfi_uploader.on(....)
Unable to get property 'on' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Did anything show up in the log? Possibly `undefined`??

Comment: I got the solution is that it was not this code problem or this plugin problem. It was wordpress setting problem.